# Prove/disprove $\{M\in GL_n({\mathbb{C}}) | M^T=M^{-1}\}$ is a group

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to solve the following:

> Prove/disprove $S:= \{M\in GL_n({\mathbb{C}}) | M^T=M^{-1}\}$ is a group

and I'm: (a) not too sure all my steps are correct; (b) stuck on the inverse part and; (c) would like to know what is the meaning of $\mathbb{C}$ (I don't seem to use this so far in the proof).

**Closure:**

Let $A,B \in S$. Then $AB \in S$ since:

$$\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$$

$$(AB)^T = B^TA^T = B^{-1}A^{-1} = (AB)^{-1}$$

**Associativity:**

Follows from associativity of matrix multiplication (i.e., if not associative, then we obtain a contradiction to matrix mult. associativity).

**Identity element** (not sure this is formal enough?)

If it exists, it must be $I$ since for all $A \in GL_n({\mathbb{C}})$ we have $AI=IA=A$. It remains to show it satisfies the other condition, and indeed $I^T=I=I^{-1}$.

**Inverse element**

**EDIT: completing the proof (deliberately very formal since the lack of formality is what got me confused in the first place, in case this helps someone else in the future)**

Let $A\in S$. We show that there exists a $B \in S$ s.t. $AB=BA=I$. We set $B := A^{-1}$ where $A^{-1}$ is the inverse of $A$ in $GL_n({\mathbb{C}})$ and thus satisfies the last equality. So $B \in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ by definition. It remains to show $B^{T}=B^{-1}$. Indeed:

$$ B^{-1} = (A^{-1})^{-1} = A$$

On the other hand, we have:

$B^{T} = (A^{-1})^T=(A^{T})^T = A$

where the second equality follows from $A$ satisfying $A^{-1} = A^T$
since $A\in S$.

Comment: Looks fine so far. The inverse is as obvious as you think it is; which matrix should you multiply $M \in \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ by to obtain the identity matrix?

Comment: @LewisMacRae Updated with proof. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Closure is correct, although I don't think the line about the determinant is necessary.

Associativity and the identity element are also correct. For the identity, all you need to show is that $I \in S$, since $I$ is already the identity in $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$. As such, just noting that $I = I^{-1} = I^T$ is perfectly rigorous.

For the inverse, suppose $A \in S$. Then we have the equation $AA^{-1} = I$ in $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$. We may then take the transpose to obtain $(A^{-1})^TA^T  = I$. Hence, $(A^{-1})^T = (A^T)^{-1}$ so that $A^{-1} \in S$ by definition.

We do not need to use $\mathbb{C}$ (the complex numbers) here; this will hold over any field.